# Type Error in python Class Method overriding too many arguments passed

Tags: python

[How to solve this issue ?? It is continuously showing that arguments are more.
Can anyone please explain me ? Also tell me alternatives to avoid such problems.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuLA2.png)

Comment: **PLEASE DO NOT POST TEXT AS IMAGES**. Copy and paste the text into your question and use the code formatting tool to format it correctly. Images are not searchable, and can not be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments. Use the [edit] link to modify your question. See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1426065) for more information.

Comment: Alternatives to avoid such problems: here's a nice article on [how to debug small programs.](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 1):

You should post the code, not an image of the code. You also need to be more specific about which kind of problem you are trying to solve, would you like to call the parent method?

The reason you are getting this error is because you're calling myMethod on an instance of the class Child, myMethod is defined as taking the parameter self only, so it will not accept a string as a second argument.

When you defined myMethod on Child it overrides the method on Parent, so calling myMethod on an instance of Child class calls myMethod from the child class so it will not accept a name parameter like the method defined on Parent.

Answer (score 1):

You have overridden myMethod in your child class. You have to understand the concept of overriding in OOP, there are a few resources you can get on the Internet.

When you defined myMethod in your child class, you have overridden the method inherited by Parent class.

The error is exactly what it is, in your overridden method, there is only one parameter defined which is the instance of the class.

When you called your method in your Child class, you have given another argument "shubham" to myMethod. This of course throws the error as you have overridden the method such that method only takes one parameter as opposed to two defined in your Parent class.

The self parameter may confuse you, but keep in mind you do not have to pass in a self argument when calling the method on an instance of a class.